# Explicitly invoking DatabaseInitializer

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I have a DbContext in an assembly that is shared between two service projects. I have both projects set to start for debugging in Visual Studio. This creates a race condition where the `DatabaseInitializer` in each service tries to update the database on startup.

To prevent this, I modified my `DbContext` as follows so as to prevent the `DatabaseIntializer` from being automatically registered.

```
public EntityContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<EntityContext>(null);
    }
}
```

I wanted to disable the `DatabaseInitializer` inside the `DbContext` itself so that I would not have to duplicate that `SetInitializer()` call in every project that happened to reference my `DbContext`, and based on what I'd read, overriding `OnModelCreating()` seemed to be the way to do it.

That prevents the `DatabaseInitializer` from running automatically, but I wanted to create a separate project that I could run manually in order to update the database. So I did something like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EntityContext>());
    new EntityContext().Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't seem to work - the null initializer set in the `OnModelCreating()` method apparently overrides anything that I specify in any other call to `SetInitializer()`. Even if I move the `SetIntializer(null)` call to a static constructor of the `EntityContext` class so as to guarantee it is called first it still doesn't work. The only way it works is if I manually call the initializer as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EntityContext>()
        .InitializeDatabase(new EntityContext());
}
```

But calling the `DatabaseInitializer.InitializeDatabase()` directly does not seem right, as the Entity Framework infrastructure is supposed to call that.

Is this a bug in EF Code First? What is the "correct" way to go about this?

**UPDATE: I decided that manually creating a database script with the `Update-Database` Package Manager Console command is a better solution than this kludgey project that tries to update the database programmatically.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work so long as the call to set the initializer is made after the call to disable the initializer. Neither OnModelCreating or the static EntityContext initializer do that in your case. The static initializer will only be called when you use EntityContext for the first time, which in your example is not until after the call to SetInitializer.

You could consider forcing a call to the static initializer before making the SetInitializer call. For example, this should work:

```
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EntityContext>());
    context.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

Comment: Nice catch... but even that code only works if I go the static constructor route. The reason is that it's actually the call to `Initialize()` that triggers the call to `OnModelCreated()`. I'm now leaning toward the idea that calling the initializer directly would be a better expression of my intent.

Comment: This is because DbContext is intentionally very lazy and does very little work, including initialization, until you actually use it in some way. This means that you don't have to know (from a perf perspective) that you will use a DbContext before creating an instance of it, which can be very useful.